# Xamarin - iPhone Distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, build, release

I have published an application on the AppStore and now I want to make a new Release for this app.

In Visual Studio I have just two build configurations, Debug and Release. The other configurations, "Ad-Hoc" and "AppStore", are missing

If I select the Release build configuration the "Archive" option is disabled, I can select just "Show the IPA file on server", if I load the file using "Load Application" it will be loaded like a testing version.

What can I do to be able to publish it like a release application?

Comment: Do you have your iOS Project as the default Startup Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that Archive menu item has been implemented in Visual Studio yet. You can do an archive from the command line. See:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/create-xcarchive/

> As of Xamarin 4.x, it is now possible to create a .xcarchive from Windows by setting the ArchiveOnBuild property to true. For example, using MSBuild on the command line:
>
> ```
> msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:ServerAddress=10.211.55.2 /p:ServerUser=xamUser /p:Platform=iPhone /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /t:"Build" MyProject.csproj
> ```
>
> The .xcarchive will be placed in the $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives directory on the Mac build host that both Xcode and Xamarin Studio search to display previously built archives.
>
> See this [Xamarin Forums post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/156635/#Comment_156635) for some brief additional notes about the ArchiveOnBuild property. See the documentation about [Xamarin.iOS command line builds on Windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/xamarin-mac-agent/#Command_Line_Support) for additional details about the ServerAddress and ServerUser properties.